# Can somebody explain to how to do this last step in this tutorial

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I am attempting to add search functionality to my Django app by using haystack and elasticsearch, and after doing some searching on google I came across this tutorial:

http://www.techstricks.com/django-haystack-and-elasticsearch-tutorial/

I followed it through the whole way, but at the end, it seems to wrap it up in a rather abrupt manner, for I didn't fully understand the last step. Could someone explain to me what the last bit of html/python was and how I can link this all to a form so I can actually search for things?

Also one last thing, in the tutorial when you add the URL:

```
(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),
```

it isn't preceded by "URL" like in other django URLs, is this conventional or typo or what? Any answers would be great, thanks.

Comment: Do you want to add `url` then add and proceed...

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand what you are saying @RajaSimon

Answer (score 0):

There is work in progress to support to match `django urls` in haystack github issues. If found any errors when you are trying to use without url then please add `url`. Hopefully they will upgrade to the latest docs soon.